# runOnUiThread() no executing when using Thread.sleep()

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm using code that looks like this :

```
_thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        operate();
                        Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Doesn't matters...
                }
            }
  };
```

operate function looks like this :

```
    // does things....
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // adds an ImageView to the screen
        }
    });
    // does other things...
```

At the bottom line, what i wanted to achieve is an operation that happens once in a while, without interrupting the main thread and the UI, something like a game-loop.

In the first 2 times that operate() runs, it adds the ImageView and everything is alright, but after 2 or 3 times it stops adding the ImageViews, but the UI is still running as usual. When i debugged the problem, i found out that after 3 times the run() method of the Runnable isn't called anymore, even thought the operate function was called.

The wired thing (for me) was that when i removed the Thread.sleep, everything worked fine (much faster of course...). I tried to replace it with a very long for loop (just for checking) and it worked, but of course it is not an appropriate solution to the problem.

I read about the problem, most of the people that asked this question did a thread.sleep or an infinite loop on the main thread, but, as i see it, i didn't do such thing. Many people wrote that you should replace the Thread.sleep with Handler.postDelayed. I tried to do it but it didn't work, maybe I did it wrong. I even tried replacing the runOnUiThread with other options I found on the internet, but all of them gave me the same exact results. I tried to replace the method that I'm adding the view to the activity, but all of them, again, gave the same result.

*The waiting is crucial for this application*. I got to find a way to wait sometime and then execute a function on the UI thread, cause this pattern returns at least a couple of times in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several reasons why the UI Runnable isn't being executed. Probably the `activity` variable has something messed up with it or it's referencing the context incorrectly, or as you said the `Thread.sleep()` could be causing an issue. At this point more parts of the code needs to viewed to better solve the problem.

A better way of implementing your logic is to use a scheduled `Timer` instead of using an infinite loop with a `Thread.sleep()` in it. It will execute the code within a background thread. And then use a `Handler` to update the UI instead of `activity.runOnUiThread()`. Here's an example:

```
// Global variable within the activity
private Handler handler;

// Activity's onCreate()
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    Timer timer = new Timer("ScheduledTask");
    // Timer must be started on the Main UI thread as such.
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            operate();
        }
    }, 0L, DELAY);
}

private void operate() {
    // does things in background....
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // adds an ImageView to the screen from within the Main UI thread
        }
    });
    // does other things in the background...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This option of Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate worked for me like a charm!

Comment: @SapirMosacho This answer leaks memory. Just FYI.

Comment: @Newtron Labs sorry for the ignorance but how?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a post delay so that you can do the code on the UI thread after some delay. [Handler Post Delay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

```
private static final int DELAY = 500;
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mRunnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start();
}

private void start()
{
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mRunnable = new MyRunnable(this);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, DELAY);
}

private void stop()
{
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}

private void doSomething()
{
    // Do your stuff here.

    // Reschedule.
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, DELAY);
}
```

Recommended way of creating a Runnable.

```
private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> mRef;

    // In here you can pass any object that you need.
    MyRunnable(MainActivity activity)
    {
        mRef = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Safety check to avoid leaking.
        MainActivity activity = mRef.get();
        if(activity == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Do something here.
        activity.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! 
I do want to post delay, but i want to do it repeatedly, i mean do something every 500 ms. How can i solve it with Handler.postDelayed?

Comment: Nothing stops you from rescheduling it again. I have updated my answer to help you out further.